# Ember sub route model method doesn't trigger when transitioning from parent

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a messages route and message sub route:

```
  // routes
  this.resource('messages');
  this.resource('message', { path: '/messages/:message_id' });
```

Due to the backend architecture (Which I have no control over) I will need to call a separate ajax call for the messages (which is really a set of message previews - no messages, just subject) and the full message object.

However Ember ignores the message route model method when coming from the messages route? It *does* trigger it when that message route is called directly. How can I can I get Ember to always call the message route model method?

Here's what I currently have:

```
App.MessageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function (params) {
    return Ember.$.ajax({
      url: '/getMessage.do'
    });
  },
  setupController: function (controller,  model) {
    console.log('model: ', model);
    console.log('model set? : ', this.get('modelLoaded'));
    var message = App.Message.create({
      message: model.data.content
    });
    controller.set('model', message);
  }
});

App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function (params) {
    return Ember.$.ajax({
      url: '/getMessagePreveiws.do'
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    var messages = [];
    model.data.forEach(function (message) {
      messages.push(App.Message.create({
        id: message.id,
        subject: message.subject,
        date: message.date_created,
        read: message.read,
        deleted: message.deleted
      }));
    });
    controller.set('model', messages); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's linking or transitioning you to the message route?

Comment: @rogMaHall no code really. Just link-to helpers: {{#each}}
 {#link-to 'message' this}}{{subject}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}

Comment: @rogMaHall But what if setupController method will not call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember designed the `model` hook to be used for going out and grabbing the appropriate data for your route when you don't have it. In your case, you're passing the data as a param via a `link-to` helper, so Ember decides it doesn't need to run the `model` hook since it already has the data.

[setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) on the other hand, should always fire (at least I haven't found otherwise...). Since it sounds like you can go directly to the url and it works, keep the model hook the way it is, but add it's content with a promise to the `setupController` hook:

```
setupController: function (controller,  model) {
  //Check if model has the data you were expecting
  //and if it doesn't, use the model hook logic
  if(Ember.isEmpty(model.data.content)){  
    Ember.$.ajax({
      url: '/getMessage.do'
    }).then(function(response){ // wait for the response... 
      var message = App.Message.create({
        message: response.data.content
      });
      controller.set('model', message);
    });
  } else {
    var message = App.Message.create({
      message: model.data.content
    });
    controller.set('model', message);
  }
}
```

Give that a try.

You can also check out [beforeModel](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel) and [afterModel](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel) to get a better idea of the route process and how they can be used as alternatives, though I think setupController is the best fit for what you're doing.